# Obtain URL's of chrome popups

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I have written a piece of code which alerts the tab URL after every 2 seconds. However, I am unable to do this for pop-ups. Whenever I open a pop-up; the tab url is of the background page and not the pop-up.

How can i get the url of the pop-up in crome?

```
<script>
var seconds = 2*1000;
setInterval(function(){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        tabId = tab.id;
        tabUrl = tab.url;
        alert(tabUrl);
});
},seconds);
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Which popup do you mean - extension's popup or popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In content_script.js or popup.html:

```
function get_urlInfo() {
   var d = {
      'action' : 'getUrl'
   };

   chrome.extension.sendRequest(d, function(response) {
       alert(response.url);
   });
};
```

In background.html:

```
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
   if (request.action == 'getUrl') {
      sendResponse({'url' : sender.tab.url});                       
   }
};

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

It should work!

Comment: shouldn't there by a click listener ? Because right now, when I click on the link; it shows no alert

Comment: No. Call get_urlInfo() in yout setTimeout function.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `null` instead of `windowId` to `chrome.tabs.getSelected()`, it defaults to "current" window, which is not necessary the selected one, as explained [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/windows.html#current-window):

> The current window is the window that contains the code that is currently executing. It's important to realize that this can be different from the topmost or focused window.

So you need to find the focused window first, and then get its selected tab:

```
var seconds = 2*1000;
setInterval(function(){
    chrome.windows.getLastFocused(function(window) {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(window.id, function(tab) {
            tabId = tab.id;
            tabUrl = tab.url;
            alert(tabUrl);
        });
    });
},seconds);
```